# What is the location of the Taskbar shortcuts for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

What is the location of the Taskbar shortcuts for Windows 10? I am looking specifically for only the icons in the dropdown box accessed by going to "Taskbar Settings" "Select Which Icons Appear On The Taskbar" page. My icons are all screwy and I need to debug this situation.

I have already checked "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\Taskbar" and they are not there.

See attached image:

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: This is not the taskbar, but the systray. However, your mistyped question and therefore the wrong answers about it are helpful

Answer (score 11):

I believe that Run5K was asking about "taskbar" shortcuts, not "systray" icons which, as you said are not shortcuts, rather elements that can be disabled/enabled from the location you specified.

The location of the taskbar icons is the same in Windows 10 as it is in Windows 7 (and I would presume is the same for Windows 8/8.1 as well, though I haven't tested):

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

Comment: First, welcome to SuperUser. Second, as you can see from the OP, Run5K is the person who last EDITED the question, not the person who asked the question. Third, OP pretty clearly states they are NOT looking for the taskbar pinned shortcuts, they actually explicitly note the location you mention and say they are NOT looking for that. Please read questions carefully before answering to make sure your answer applies and is correct.

Comment: or press Win+R and type `shell:User Pinned\TaskBar`

Answer (score 4):

You can access Windows Task Pinned Shortcut Folder from Windows Run :

- Windows + R
- Type : `shell:User Pinned\Taskbar`
- Press "OK" or "Enter"

*Shout-out to [Geograph](https://superuser.com/users/552011/geograph) who provided this answer as a comment. (I Added proper wording to help search engine)

Comment: Nice and clean, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

These are not static shortcuts. They are applications that are running on the computer. There is not a folder that contains the items found here.

Windows gives you some control over which system app icons will show here:

Right-click on your Taskbar and select **Taskbar Settings**.

Scroll down to **Notification Area** and click **Select which icons appear on the taskbar** or **Turn system icons on or off** and make your selections there.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I found what appears to be my taskbar shortcuts here: %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

Although editing these values does not  appear to impact my taskbar - yet. Maybe after reboot.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your post is incomplete.  If would be more helpful to give the answer after you reboot.  You will find that you will have a better experience if you take moment to take the Stack Overflow [tour].  If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: I guess that I have not logged in for a few months. It appears that my answer is not relevant to the question, but it makes you wonder why my task bar settings are located under 'Internet Explorer', when I don't even have IE installed.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I find the same on my computer.  Recommend you post as a question and see.